# Duplicating a class

Tags: php, class, function

I am currently using a pagination script that uses a class named "pagination". I would like to duplicate this class in another file to use it again.  I'm having problems with my framework recognizing it as "duplicate".  I know that changing it should be as simple as changing the class name, but there are several functions within the class that makes it too complex for me to figure out.

So my question is, based on the code below, what variables, functions, values, etc. would I need to change in my class in order to create an identical copy of it?

```
class pagination {
/*
   Script Name: *Digg Style Paginator Class
   Script URI: http://www.mis-algoritmos.com/2007/05/27/digg-style-pagination-class/
   Description: Class in PHP that allows to use a pagination like a digg or sabrosus style.
   Script Version: 0.4
   Author: Victor De la Rocha
   Author URI: http://www.mis-algoritmos.com
*/
/*Default values*/
var $total_pages    = - 1; //items
var $limit          = null;
var $target         = "";
var $page           = 1;
var $adjacents      = 2;
var $showCounter    = false;
var $className      = "pagination";
var $parameterName  = "pg";
var $urlF           = false; //urlFriendly
/*Buttons next and previous*/
var $nextT          = "Next";
var $nextI          = "&#187;"; //&#9658;
var $prevT          = "Previous";
var $prevI          = "&#171;"; //&#9668;

var $calculate      = false;
// Total items
function items($value) {
    $this->total_pages  = (int) $value;
}
// how many items to show per page
function limit($value) {
    $this->limit        = (int) $value;
}
// Page to sent the page value
function target($value) {
    $this->target       = $value;
}
// Current page
function currentPage($value) {
    $this->page         = (int) $value;
}
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side of the current page?
function adjacents($value) {
    $this->adjacents    = (int) $value;
}
// show counter?
function showCounter($value = "") {
    $this->showCounter  = ($value === true)?true:false;
}
// to change the class name of the pagination div
function changeClass($value = "") {
    $this->className    = $value;
}

function nextLabel($value) {
    $this->nextT        = $value;
}
function nextIcon($value) {
    $this->nextI        = $value;
}
function prevLabel($value) {
    $this->prevT        = $value;
}
function prevIcon($value) {
    $this->prevI        = $value;
}
// to change the class name of the pagination div
function parameterName($value = "") {
    $this->parameterName = $value;
}
// to change urlFriendly
function urlFriendly($value = "%") {
    if (eregi('^ *$', $value)) {
        $this->urlF = false;
        return false;
    }
    $this->urlF = $value;
}

var $pagination;
function pagination() {
}
function show() {
    if (!$this->calculate) {
        if ($this->calculate()) {
            echo "<div class=\"$this->className\">$this->pagination</div>\n";
        }
    }
}
function getOutput() {
    if (!$this->calculate) {
        if ($this->calculate()) {
            return "<div class=\"$this->className\">$this->pagination</div>\n";
        }
    }
}
function get_pagenum_link($id) {
    if (strpos($this->target, '?') === false)
        if ($this->urlF)
            return str_replace($this->urlF, $id, $this->target);
        else
            return "$this->target?$this->parameterName=$id";
    else
        return "$this->target&$this->parameterName=$id";
}

function calculate() {
    $this->pagination = "";
    $this->calculate == true;
    $error = false;
    if ($this->urlF and $this->urlF != '%' and strpos($this->target, $this->urlF) === false) {
        // Es necesario especificar el comodin para sustituir
        echo "Especificaste un wildcard para sustituir, pero no existe en el target<br />";
        $error = true;
    } elseif ($this->urlF and $this->urlF == '%' and strpos($this->target, $this->urlF) === false) {
        echo "Es necesario especificar en el target el comodin % para sustituir el n?mero de p?gina<br />";
        $error = true;
    }

    if ($this->total_pages <0) {
        echo "It is necessary to specify the <strong>number of pages</strong> (\$class->items(1000))<br />";
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($this->limit == null) {
        echo "It is necessary to specify the <strong>limit of items</strong> to show per page (\$class->limit(10))<br />";
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($error)return false;

    $n = trim($this->nextT . ' ' . $this->nextI);
    $p = trim($this->prevI . ' ' . $this->prevT);

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    if ($this->page)
        $start = ($this->page - 1) * $this->limit; //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0; //if no page var is given, set start to 0
    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    $prev = $this->page - 1; //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $this->page + 1; //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($this->total_pages / $this->limit); //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; //last page minus 1
    /*
       Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object.
       We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */

    if ($lastpage > 1) {
        if ($this->page) {
            // anterior button
            if ($this->page > 1)
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($prev) . "\" class=\"prev\">$p</a>";
            else
                $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">$p</span>";
        }
        // pages
        if ($lastpage <7 + ($this->adjacents * 2)) { // not enough pages to bother breaking it up
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $this->page)
                    $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($counter) . "\">$counter</a>";
            }
        } elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($this->adjacents * 2)) { // enough pages to hide some
            // close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if ($this->page <1 + ($this->adjacents * 2)) {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <4 + ($this->adjacents * 2); $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $this->page)
                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($counter) . "\">$counter</a>";
                }
                $this->pagination .= "...";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($lpm1) . "\">$lpm1</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($lastpage) . "\">$lastpage</a>";
            }
            // in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif ($lastpage - ($this->adjacents * 2) > $this->page && $this->page > ($this->adjacents * 2)) {
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link(1) . "\">1</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link(2) . "\">2</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "...";
                for ($counter = $this->page - $this->adjacents; $counter <= $this->page + $this->adjacents; $counter++)
                    if ($counter == $this->page)
                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($counter) . "\">$counter</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "...";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($lpm1) . "\">$lpm1</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($lastpage) . "\">$lastpage</a>";
            }
            // close to end; only hide early pages
            else {
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link(1) . "\">1</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link(2) . "\">2</a>";
                $this->pagination .= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($this->adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    if ($counter == $this->page)
                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($counter) . "\">$counter</a>";
            }
        }
        if ($this->page) {
            // siguiente button
            if ($this->page <$counter - 1)
                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"" . $this->get_pagenum_link($next) . "\" class=\"next\">$n</a>";
            else
                $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">$n</span>";
            if ($this->showCounter)$this->pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination_data\">($this->total_pages Pages)</div>";
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: why would you need an *identical* copy of it? That makes no sense.

Comment: Now that wouldn't be very [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) would it?

Comment: HI Gordon, I have two separate files that each contain this single class.  I would like to keep them in separate files and rename them because they are conflicting with each other when I call them from my functions.php file in Wordpress

Comment: @RobMyrick ... so split out the class into it's own file and `include` that other file in the other two?

Comment: Hi Charles, wanted to let you know that I took your suggestion above and structured my class in it's own file.  I'm still having a conflict though due to Wordpress's auto-inclusion of all files with a `require_once` attached to it.  When I comment out the code, including one of the non-class files, my code works correctly.  It seems as if duplicating the class under a different name would work great, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **include** the file which holds the pagination class **only once**!

Use `incldue_once` or `require_once` instead of `include` and `require`.